# Having Problem with ipython notebook on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python

I have installed ipython notebook in my system, but when I want to run it in terminal, the following error comes up:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-3.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tornado import iostream
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, ssl_match_hostname, SSLCertificateError, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 39, in <module>
    import certifi
ImportError: No module named certifi
```

Does any one know where the problem is? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a dependency for IPython Notebook.  If you don't already have `pip` installed, I would recommend installing it for the ease of installing python packages:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential`

Once pip has been installed, you can install the IPython Notebook and all its dependencies by entering at the command line:

`pip install "ipython[notebook]"`

You may have to run that one with `sudo` as well if you get an error.