# Getting started with iPython notebook

Tags: kubuntu, python, ipython

Please don't consider this a duplicate.  I have seen a similar post and the recommended solution has not solved my issue.  I need input for I can't find a solution elsewhere and iPython does not seem to have a support forum.

I am trying to use iPython notebook on Kubuntu 14.04 but can not get it to launch.  I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646959/having-problem-with-ipython-notebook-on-ubuntu-14-04/647326#647326/%22this%20post%22) and tried the [recommended solution of installing dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/a/647326/53623). The system states that python-pip and python-dev are already the newest version.  There is no response for build-essential.

If one uses `pip` to install a python package, does it make a difference which Python interpreter is launched?  Troubleshooting this issue I discovered Python 2.7.6 & 3.4.0 are installed on my system.  Would that make a difference?  From my reading of the requirements, iPython should work on either version of Python.

In research to find a solution I came across `ipython notebook --notebook-dir='<path/to/notebooks>'`. I set the variable to a path under my home directory.  That did not make a difference.  If it try to start by entering `ipython notebook` I get the following Tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('13', 'IPython.html')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 12, in check_for_zmq
    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13
```

**Additional questions**

After Steve Barnes  advice I am not sure everything working as it should.  For iPython to work, I had to create the directory for notebooks under the root of all other websites on my machine.

Entering `ipython notebook` in a command prompt I get the following output:

```
16:33:11 Fri Jul 31 - ~/www/ipython_notebooks
$> ipython notebook
[I 16:33:15.571 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
[I 16:33:15.588 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/daniel/www/ipython_notebooks
[I 16:33:15.588 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 16:33:15.589 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 16:33:15.589 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 16:33:16.801 NotebookApp] 405 HEAD /tree (127.0.0.1) 5.74ms referer=None
```

In my browser the url is unexpected.  It displays as

```
file:///var/tmp/kdecache-daniel/krun/6915_0_tree
```

and the content appears as HTML with no CSS. Any links or dropdowns don't work.
To get the web page to work as expected it is necessary to type the url `http://localhost:8888/notebooks/` explicitly. The page rendered next is unexpected either for Jupyter and not iPython.

I would like to include screenshots but apparently I don't have sufficient reputation to do so.  I feel there is something I am missing.  Can someone offer if they have had a similar result and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line tells what your problem is:

```
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13
```

Your system either has no pyzmq or an old version - try:

```
sudo pip install -U pyzmq
```

*The -U is the same as --upgrade and will request the installation of the latest version of pyzmq that is compatible with your version of python.*

You may have to install some other dependencies to get this to work such as the python-dev package that matches your current version of python, which will need to be installed with `apt-get install`.

There may well be additional unmet and optional dependencies of iPython and its notebook for you to meet, for the majority `sudo pip install -U` *name_of_component* will do the trick. *I would also suggest reading up on python [virtual-env](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)*

### Some more notes

Once iPython is running in notebook mode you will need browse to localhost:8888http://tree or //localhost:8888/tree as is shown by the last line in the command window, *note that /tree is a view type not an actual directory and any notebooks and sub-directories in directory that you started iPython from will be shown*.

You may also be confused to see that the server is now called **jupyter** this is because the notebook functionality from iPython has grown into, and is now being maintained and developed as, a [separate project](https://jupyter.org/) that supports Python 2/3, Julia, R, Haskell, Ruby and many other languages.

One server can open kernels running any of them that you have installed on your machine as well as you being able to mix some of them in a single notebook by using the magic commands.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and help.  With what I saw on iPython's web site it was not clear that iPython and iPython notebook are two separate things.  Based on your lead and discovering other dependencies I think something is still not right.  Please see amended component to original question.

Comment: @dwlamb - Added some more information in my answer that addresses your additional concerns & confusions.